# Cmus add modplug

Tags: cmus

I use cmus on my BigSur, and I install the libmodplug and libmikmod.
my cmus still doesn't support mod

`cmus --plugins`:

```
Input Plugins: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmus/2.9.1/lib/cmus/ip
  mad:
    Priority: 55
    File Types: mp3 mp2
    MIME Types: audio/mpeg audio/x-mp3 audio/x-mpeg
  opus:
    Priority: 50
    File Types: opus
    MIME Types:
  wav:
    Priority: 50
    File Types: wav
    MIME Types:
  mp4:
    Priority: 50
    File Types: mp4 m4a m4b
    MIME Types:
  cue:
    Priority: 50
    File Types:
    MIME Types: application/x-cue
  aac:
    Priority: 50
    File Types: aac
    MIME Types: audio/aac audio/aacp
  flac:
    Priority: 50
    File Types: flac fla
    MIME Types:
  vorbis:
    Priority: 50
    File Types: ogg oga ogx
    MIME Types: application/ogg audio/x-ogg
  ffmpeg:
    Priority: 30
    File Types: aa aac ac3 aif aifc aiff ape au fla flac m4a m4b mka mkv mp+ mp2 mp3 mp4 mpc mpp ogg opus shn tak tta wav webm wma wv
    MIME Types:

Output Plugins: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmus/2.9.1/lib/cmus/op
  coreaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install modplug manually and reinstall cmus from source

```
brew install libmodplug
brew reinstall -s cmus
```